# Dancing Links in GAP

Tags: algorithm, gap-system

I am working on a combinatorics problem that has connections to group theory, and I decided to do the group theoretic part in GAP (b/c GAP is really efficient in that area).
Now, the computations involve finding an exact cover in a certain configuration, and the most straightforward way to tackle this is using Knuth's Algorithm X for backtracking.

I was wondering (especially since the 'A' in 'GAP' stands for 'Algorithms') whether a GAP implementation of the Algorithm X / Dancing Links has already been implemented and can be reused. I haven't found anything about it in the docs; has anyone else come across something like that?

Comment: Please ask this question in the [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) or if you prefer StackExchange framework, at [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info) site - the `gap` tag is there and it gets much more attention than here.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks for the reply - I already crossposted my question to MathematicsStackExchange because I saw the hint. (I do think however that it is not really a math question, so the proper place **should** be here.) If I get no further replies, I'll try the GAP forum next.

Comment: [Here's a link to the corresponding question on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1455020/167197)